# Htaccess PHP ignore all gets except of first

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

My `$GET` parameter could be `url` with another paramenters `(mysite.co/index.php?q=anothersite.co?id=2)` and i need to ignore them.

But im getting lost them `(mysite.co/index.php?q=anothersite.co)` after going to the url.

How i can fix it? Without decoding url.

Comment: you need to url encode the parameters you pass to q on the client side.

Comment: Multiple GET requests in the URL are actually separated with a `&` Example:`http://example.com/?test=example&test2=example2`

Comment: no other way? I need to have not encoded url :(

Comment: I need to store another websites pages, that's why i cant modify them

Comment: I dont need multiple GET i just need to have one GET with url

Comment: using javascript `.replace` you could replace `?` and `&` and `=` to other values, and then replace them back on server side.

Comment: But how i can carry which were replaced by my javascript and which are not on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `&` instead of another `?`

this should work

```
mysite.co/index.php?q=anothersite.co&id=2
```

EDIT:

```
$encoded = encode("http://anothersite.co?id=2");
```

and then

```
mysite.co/index.php?q=$encode
```

Comment: i need to have original `anothersite.co` url in my `GET`

Comment: Ok then if it possible to pass all after `mysite.co/` into `PHP` variable, BUT dont show it in the browser - for example `mysite.co/anysite.co?id=123` ??

Comment: @user3623906 I have edited the answer. you have to use encode method for that like google does

Comment: i need to have pure urls, not encoded for user pasting into bar.

Comment: Anyway when i encode them the part after 2nd `?` is missing after going to that url

Comment: @user3623906 you are using `"q"`  on your index.php page so in your `index.php` page you have to decode the uri `decode($_GET['q'])`